# Checkbox array in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of checkboxes, coming from a main system object where I store all system setting.  (called getSystem{}).

In this form, Im accessing a User, which has an array of roles [].
How can I check this array of roles, against the getSystem.user_roles?

I know how to do it normally, in javascript obviously.  But what would I put in the checkbox input Vue.js wise?

```
    <b-form-group>
      <label for="company">Email Address</label>
      <b-form-input type="text" id="email" v-model="user.email" placeholder="Enter a valid e-mail"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
    // Here i can do user.roles to get the array of roles.
    // What can I do to loop through the roles and check the box if it exists in the user roles??
    <b-form-group v-for="resource, key in getSystem.user_roles" v-if="getSystem.user_roles">
       <label>{{resource.role_name}}</label>
       <input type="checkbox" [ what do I put here to compare against user.roles, and check the box if exists??]  > 
    </b-form-group>
```

Comment: not sure the schema for `getSystem.user_roles` and `user.roles`, it seems be like this `<input type="checkbox" :checked="user.roles[resource.role_name]"  >`?

Comment: Its an array of objects though.  So I need to check resource.id against each object inside user.roles.   so foreach user.roles as role, resource.id == role.id etc

Answer (score 55):

This behavior is well documented on the [Checkbox binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) Docs.

Here a little example emulating your logic

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      roles: [{id: 1, name: 'Client'}]
    },
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Client',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Guest',
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />
  </div>
  <div v-for="role in roles" :key="role.id">
    <label>{{role.name}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="user.roles" :value="role"/>
  </div>
  
  <p>User's selected roels</p>
  {{user.roles}}
</div>
```

Comment: but in my case user.roles is an array of objects.  Not just an array of numbers/keys\

Comment: it's the same logic but with objects, check the edited code.. and if the ```getSystem.user_roles``` have a different format, just map it to the shape of the user.roles

Answer (score 17):

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-model="userRoles" :true-value="[]" :value="resource.role_name">
```

You should add `:true-value="[]"`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use dynamic check box input rendering with the condition to select values from the customized function (in my example `selectUsers`). In that function, we can write conditions that we need to compare before append to the selected array.

Demo:

[image]

This is the full NuxtJs(vue) component with dummy data.

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <p>{{selected }}</p>
    <div v-for="user in user_roles" :key="user[0]">
    <input type="checkbox"
      @click="()=>{selectUsers(user[0])}"
      :value="user[0]"
    >
    {{user[1]}}
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'
import lodash from 'lodash'
export default {
    
    data() {
    return {
      user_roles:[[1,"dd"],[2,"ddd"],[3,"kksse"],[4,"kske"]] ,
      selected:[],
    };
  },
  methods: {
      selectUsers(id){
          //in here you can check what ever condition  before append to array.
          if(this.selected.includes(id)){
              this.selected=_.without(this.selected,id)
          }else{
              this.selected.push(id)
          }
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<b-form-group v-for="resource, key in getSystem.user_roles" v-if="getSystem.user_roles" :key="key">
   <label>{{resource.role_name}}</label>
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="userRoles" :value="resource.role_name"  > 
</b-form-group>

<script>
  data(){
    return {
      userRoles: []
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This options is not working for me currently. Not down voting  just not upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as I am server rendering the checkboxes, what worked for me is to replace `:value` with just `value`

```
@foreach($carOptions as $option)
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="mx-2 form-check-input cursor-pointer"
           type="checkbox"
           value="{{$option}}" <------ HERE in order for vue to work I had to change from :value to value
           v-model="offer.carOptions">
    <label class="custom-control-label cursor-pointer"
           for="leading">{{ __($option) }}</label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

NOTE: The code snippet is a Laravel Blade Templates.