# VueJS: filter select lists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a VueJS application. I have two lists: A, B

- A contains all elements
- B contains some elements from A

I have `<select>` tags. Each select tag must hold the value of a B element, and should have the option to select other values of A which are not contained in B.

Question: how can I properly filter the elements of A which don't exist in B, with exception for the element the tag has selected at that point? A generic solution is to iterate over each element and unset the undesired ones from lists. The problem is Vue has reactive properties, which means when I change the list for a custom select, change is propagated to other selects as well.

I've wrapped my head for over an hour. I believe I'm building scenarios for a simple question which has a simple solution, but I can't find it. Please assist me.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      b: [],
      a: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterElements() {
      return this.a.filter((a, a_index) => {
        return !this.b.find((b, b_index) => {
          return a === b
        })
      })
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="i in b.length">
 <select v-model="b[i-1]">
     <option value="0" disabled>Select a value</option>
     <!--<option v-for="(item, index) in filterElements()" :value="item">{{ item }}</option> doesn't work -->
     <option v-for="(item, index) in a" :value="item">{{ item }}</option>
 </select>
 <br>
   
  </template>
  <br>
  <button @click="b.push(0)">+</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>Selected elements: {{ b.join(', ') }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a computed property to contained the filtered version of A

To track changes in B you have to use `$set` to update the elements in B.
Otherwise B will not be reactive. More information here, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      b: [],
      a: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredA() {
      return this.a.filter((a, a_index) => {
        return !this.b.find((b, b_index) => {
          return a === b
        })
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateB(e, i) {
      // use $set to update array elements to maintain reactivity
      this.$set(this.b, i, +e);
    }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="i in b.length">
    <select :value="b[i-1]" @input="updateB($event.target.value, i-1)">
            <option :value="b[i-1]">{{b[i-1] || "Select a value"}}</option>
        <!--<option v-for="(item, index) in filterElements()" :value="item">{{ item }}</option> doesn't work -->
        <option v-for="(item, index) in filteredA" :value="item" :key="`${item}-${index}`">{{ item }}</option>
    </select>
    <br>
            
  </template>
  <br>
  <button @click="b.push(0)">+</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>Selected elements: {{ b.join(', ') }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think I found the problem, changes in elements of B does not cause the `filteredA` to change, it's because vue's reactivity does not trigger in array element change if changed directly.

Can you check if the updated solution works ? @user8555937

Comment: Try out the snippet and see if it yields the desired result

Comment: Lovely! Thank you

Comment: The selection box returns the selected value as string which is denoted as `e`. The `+` sign before `e`  simply converts it into a number

Answer (score 0):

No need to manually filter. Here is a solution with looping your `a` array, and binding the selected values to `b`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50648659/13602136

Comment: Doesn't answer my question

Comment: Ohh, right, sorry. Question: what is the use case here? Each generated `select` would filter out the already selected options? Why don't you use just one multi-select?

Comment: One multi select might do the trick. Though I have to keep this layout for some reasons.

Comment: Each generated select must contain all elements from A which are not present in B

Comment: I think you will need to v-model with a [computed setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter), and use the `.splice()` method on your `A` array, to remove or add the items.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to do an array substraction (element in A that are not in B):

```js
function aNotInB(a, b) {
  return a.filter(aElement => {
    // .find() returns undefined if nothing is found
    // (b.find(element) === undefined) returns true if a element is not found in b
    return b.find(bElement => aElement === bElement) === undefined
  })
}

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 3, 4]


console.log(aNotInB(a,b))    // [1, 5]
```

Comment: It's the same thing I did. Check the snippet