# How to bind the checked checkbox with corresponding input element into an array in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm not sure I titled my question correctly but would try to explain better, please bear with me.

So I have a form in my component template, I'm looping through an object called fruits in the form to display available fruits so that one can tick fruits they want and indicate the numbers they want. Here is how the form looks like[image]

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #4d94d1; color:white;"><h4>Please Enter Details</h4> </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputname">Name</label>
                            <input v-model="form.name" type="text" name="name"
                                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                                class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name') }">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputemail">Email</label>
                            <input v-model="form.email" type="text" name="email"
                                placeholder="Email"
                                class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email') }">
                            <has-error :form="form" field="email"></has-error>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                        
                            <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Check</th>
                                <th scope="col">Size</th>
                                <th scope="col">Enter Number Requesting</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
                                <th scope="row">{{ index +1 }}</th>
                                <td>{{ fruit.name }}</td>
                                <td><div class="form-group small" >
                                        <input v-model="form.selectedFruits" v-bind:value="fruit.id" type="checkbox" />
                                    </div></td>
                                <td>{{ fruit.size }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group small" >
                                        <input name="" class="form-control" type="number"  />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputphone">Phone</label>
                            <input v-model="form.phone" type="text" name="phone"
                                placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                                class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('phone') }">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputaddress">Address</label>
                            <input v-model="form.address" type="text" name="address"
                                placeholder="Enter address"
                                class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('address') }">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                fruits: {},
                form: new Form({
                id: '',
                name: '',
                email: '',
                phone: '',
                address: '',
                selectedFruits: []
                })
            }
        },
        methods: {
            //define method to send an http request using axois to the apiResource
            getFruit() {
            axios.get('api/fruits')
            .then(({data }) => (this.fruits = data));
            }
        },
        created() {
            //On DOM created execute function
            this.getFruit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The challenge is I don't seem to know how to bind the ids of fruits selected with the corresponding numbers they want into selectedFruits.

PS: I'm able to bind the selected fruits but I need to know the number of each fruit they want. That is the number inputted into the form.

Here is the data structure of the fruit data that I'm looping through

```
fruits: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Mango',
        size: 'Big
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Banana',
        size: 'Medium
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Apple',
        size: 'Medium
      }
    ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648407/checkbox-array-in-vue-js

Comment: `selectedFruits` should only contain the IDs of the currently selected fruits - if you know the IDs, you can always find the corresponding quantities.

Comment: @Mathix420 Thank you for your response. Not really, in that case, the data was predefined, so binding the data to the checkbox was straightforward. In my own case, I want to know the quantity requested for every fruit selected as they would be entered newly.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the ```fruit``` or ```fruits``` object structure/properties? In ```data``` you initialize ```fruits``` as an empty object, but use it in your template as an array in ```v-for```.  Seems inconsistent.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your response. fruits is an object am getting when DOM is created through an api call. It's the fruits data that is being looped through within the table to display the id, name and size of the fruits available to the customer. I would update my question to show the structure of data if you still feels so but if look at the image uploaded, you'd see the important field are the id , name and size.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks for your response. Yea, that's what I tried doing but I seem not to be able to figure it out. If you look at my code you would see I get the selectedFruits' id but from there it's dead ends. I can't post all the ways I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to my comment, I created a Single File Component to address what seems to be your core problem of binding the ids of fruits to the corresponding numbers. My example shows how to add a `quantity` property to each `fruit` object and update the quantity in the form.

I simplified the form and removed the checkbox tracking for simplicity, but you should be able to use this functionality with your form.

```
<template>
  <div class="add-object-property">
    <h4>Select Fruit</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Size</th>
                <th scope="col">Enter Number Requesting</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.id">
                <th scope="row">{{ fruit.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ fruit.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ fruit.size }}</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-group small">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="fruit.quantity"/>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fruits: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Mango',
            size: 'Big'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Banana',
            size: 'Medium'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Apple',
            size: 'Medium'
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getFruit() {
        // Simulate API call
        setTimeout(this.addQuantity(), 1000);
      },
      addQuantity() {
        this.fruits.forEach(fruit => {
          this.$set(fruit, 'quantity', 0);
        });
      },
      submitForm() {
        console.log(this.fruits);
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getFruit();
      console.log(this.fruits);
    }
  }
</script>
```